# app deploys from vs but not launching on simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, ios-simulator

I am trying to run my app in simulator it start deploying in visual studio but not launching on simulator.

even if I manually open that simulator app doesn't runs over there.while is shows running in vs

[image]

please help if anyone have idea whats going wrong here

Comment: Please post more details. Whether you are facing the problem about connecting to Mac from Windows? If so, please read [this documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) for more details.

Comment: no i am not facing issue in connection. mac succesfuly connected.can see all simulator name list in VS too.i can run app.it shows running as above image.but on mac cant see simulator

Comment: Please make sure if your app has run successfully. From your screenshot, It seems something is wrong. Please tap ErrorList to see more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was due to memory issue of mac.

mac memory was full so it was unable to launch simulator.as i have cleared memory and make more free space it start ruining now.

thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Xcode installed in your mac. Make sure Xcode is running in your mac. If you are using vs from windows make sure you are on the same network with the mac, and you are connected to it. You can always try to change the simulator in which you deploy it. Also check the simulator if the app you want to run is installing in the simulator. You should wait until it's installed to run your app. I hope it helps this time. :)

Comment: thank you for your reply but  i am not talking  about emulator.
facing this problem for ios simulator on mac

Comment: Oh, well sorry for not reading the question thoroughly. I will edit my question if I could anyhow help.

Comment: You don't need to be on the same network when you are connecting to the Mac machine.

Comment: i have checked all the points.and i was running my app on simulator also.
suddenly dont know what happensed started facing this issue